# React state updates without a setState function - Unexpected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have a few chat components, `chat` (parent), `CreateMessage`(child), and `DisplayMessages`(child). All three components will be shown below.

The user creates a message with the `CreateMessage` component. It saves it in the useState hook, `indivMessages`, stored in the parent `Chat` component.

The `indivMessages` are sent to the `DisplayMessages` component. It displays the messages as well as groups messages by the same author together based off the user id.

The problem is, the `indivMessages` state is getting set with the value from `formattedMessages`, which is only set inside the `useEffect` hook in `DisplayMessages`.

Why is `indivMessages` getting set with the value for `formattedMessages`??

For the sake of this example, I commented out all of the socket stuff to just work in a sterile environment - the same results will happen both ways.

Chat.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { SocketContext } from "src/SocketContext";

import CreateMessage from "./details/CreateMessage";
import DisplayMessages from "./details/DisplayMessages";

export default function Chat(props) {
  const state = useSelector((state) => state);
  const [indivMessages, setIndivMessages] = useState([]);
  const socket = useContext(SocketContext);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (state.chatShow) {
  //     socket.emit("SUBSCRIBE_CHAT", state.chat.chatRoom);
  //     return () => {
  //       socket.emit("UNSUBSCRIBE", state.chat.chatRoom);
  //     };
  //   }
  // });

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   socket.on("new_message", (data) => {
  //     setIndivMessages([...indivMessages, data]);
  //   });
  //   return () => {
  //     socket.off("new_message");
  //   };
  // }, [socket, indivMessages]);

  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-column h-100 justify-content-end">
      <DisplayMessages state={state} indivMessages={indivMessages} />
      <CreateMessage
        state={state}
        indivMessages={indivMessages}
        setIndivMessages={setIndivMessages}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

CreateMessage.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";

import { CInputGroup, CInput, CInputGroupAppend, CButton } from "@coreui/react";
import CIcon from "@coreui/icons-react";
import { SocketContext } from "src/SocketContext";

export default function CreateMessage(props) {
  const { indivMessages, setIndivMessages, state } = props;
  const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState("");
  const socket = useContext(SocketContext);

  const sendMessage = () => {
    let messageTemplate = {
      messages: [{ msg: newMessage }],
      username: state.user.username,
      _id: indivMessages.length + 1,
      ownerId: state.user._id,
      picture: state.user.picture,
      chatRoom: state.chat.chatRoom,
      date: Date.now(),
    };
    // socket.emit("create_message", messageTemplate);
    setIndivMessages((msgs) => [...msgs, messageTemplate]);
    document.getElementById("msgInput").value = "";
  };

  return (
    <CInputGroup style={{ position: "relative", bottom: 0 }}>
      <CInput
        type="text"
        style={{ fontSize: "18px" }}
        id="msgInput"
        className="rounded-0"
        placeholder="Type a message here..."
        autoComplete="off"
        onChange={(e) => setNewMessage(e.target.value)}
        onKeyUp={(e) => e.code === "Enter" && sendMessage()}
      />
      <CInputGroupAppend>
        <CButton color="success" className="rounded-0" onClick={sendMessage}>
          <CIcon name="cil-send" />
        </CButton>
      </CInputGroupAppend>
    </CInputGroup>
  );
}
```

DisplayMessages.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { CContainer, CCard, CImg, CCol, CLabel } from "@coreui/react";

export default function DisplayMessages(props) {
  const { indivMessages, state } = props;
  const [formattedMessages, setFormattedMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //Create Grouped Messesges
    let messagesArray = [...indivMessages];
    let sortedArray = messagesArray.sort((a, b) => {
      return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
    });

    let grouped = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
      let index = grouped.length - 1;
      if (sortedArray[i].ownerId === grouped[index]?.ownerId) {
        let lastMessage = grouped.pop();
        sortedArray[i].messages[0]._id = sortedArray[i]._id;
        lastMessage.messages = [
          ...lastMessage.messages,
          sortedArray[i].messages[0],
        ];
        grouped.push(lastMessage);
      } else {
        console.log(i, grouped.length);
        grouped.push(sortedArray[i]);
      }
    }
    setFormattedMessages(grouped);
  }, [indivMessages]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let msgContainer = document.getElementById("msgContainer");
    msgContainer.scrollTop = msgContainer.scrollHeight;
  }, [formattedMessages]);

  return (
    <CContainer
      className="mt-2 no-scroll-bar"
      style={{ overflow: "auto", maxHeight: "85vh" }}
      id="msgContainer"
    >
      {formattedMessages.map((msg) => {
        return (
          <CCard
            key={msg._id}
            className="d-flex flex-row p-2"
            color="secondary"
            accentColor={state.user._id === msg.ownerId && "primary"}
          >
            <CImg
              src={msg.picture}
              alt={msg.owner}
              className="w-25 align-self-start rounded"
            />
            <CCol>
              <CLabel>
                <strong>{msg.username}</strong>
              </CLabel>
              {msg.messages.map((message) => {
                return (
                  <p key={message._id ? message._id : msg._id}>{message.msg}</p>
                );
              })}
            </CCol>
          </CCard>
        );
      })}
    </CContainer>
  );
}
```

I am thinking that something is going on within the `useEffect` hook in the `DisplayMessages` component. This function executes every time the `indivMessages` array changes.

It creates grouped messages by checking if the newest message's author (`ownerId`), is the same as the previous message's author. If they are the same, it extracts all the messages from the message itself, and adds them to the previous message's message key in order to create grouped messages.

This result is what is being set in the `indivMessages` array, which is unexpected since I do not set `indivMessages` with grouped messages!

Thanks for your help and thanks for some pointers in the right direction!

Comment: There's a **lot** of code above. Please reduce it to a [mcve], removing anything unnecessary to replicating the problem. To help people help you, make your MRE **runnable** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `useEffect` code, you're **modifying** the objects in `sortedArray`, which are also held in `indivMessages`. For instance:

```
sortedArray[i].messages[0]._id = sortedArray[i]._id;
```

Your code setting up `sortedArray` just copies the **array**, not the objects within it. If you want to modify those objects, you need to make copies first. For instance, the example above becomes:

```
sortedArray[i] = {
    ...sortedArray[i],
    messages: [{...sortedArray[i].messages[0], _id = sortedArray[i]._id}, ...sortedArray[i].messages.slice(1)],
};
```

...or similar.

You have the same sort of problem with:

```
lastMessage.messages = [
  ...lastMessage.messages,
  sortedArray[i].messages[0],
];
```

...but probably want to solve it elsewhere (perhaps by changing `grouped.push(sortedArray[i]);` to `grouped.push({...sortedArray[i]});`, but I haven't done a really deep read of that code).

Comment: Thanks for showing me the SO snippets in the original comment above - I'll use these in the future as it seems like a much better way to show things off in a usable way! -- `grouped.push({...sortedArray[i]});` is magic and works exactly as intended! Thanks so much for your help. I have been banging my head off the wall since about 6pm last night trying to figure out why this was working the way it was. Weirdly, it was intermittent! It started working as intended last night around 11, and this morning went back to the problem above. Thanks T.J. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @NickMcLean - I'm glad that helped! Happy coding! :-)